# Complex Integral Question

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals

I'm trying to evaluate the following integral, in preparation for my exam tomorrow;

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(2x) - 1}{x^2} dx$$

However, I'm having a lot of issues with it. I was initially trying an argument involving $e^{2iz}$, but I can't seem to work in that constant.

I know that the contour I should be evaluating is going to be a half annulus, as the singularity occurs at $x = 0$, but I'm really just not sure what I'm aiming for here.

Anything to start me off would be fantastic, thank you!!

Comment: [Alternate forms](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cos%282x%29-1).

Comment: Awesome, thank you, got it!! :D

Comment: If no one answers by tomorrow or so, it would be nice if you could post an answer to the problem yourself, so the question doesn't come up as unanswered.

Answer (score 3):

There are of course many ways to evaluate the integral. If we're using $e^{2iz}$ and the boundary of a half-annulus as the contour, we should use the parity of the integrand and start with

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos (2x)-1}{x^2}\,dx &= \frac{1}{2} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos (2x)-1}{x^2}\,dx\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\lim_{\substack{\varepsilon\to 0\\ R\to\infty}} \left(\int_{-R}^{-\varepsilon}\frac{\cos (2x)-1}{x^2}\,dx + \int_\varepsilon^R \frac{\cos (2x) - 1}{x^2}\,dx\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\lim_{\substack{\varepsilon\to 0\\ R\to\infty}} \left(\int_{-R}^{-\varepsilon}\frac{e^{2ix}-1}{x^2}\,dx + \int_\varepsilon^R \frac{e^{2ix} - 1}{x^2}\,dx\right),
\end{align}$$

where the last equality is due to the oddness of $\sin$. Now writing $s_r$ for the semicircle of radius $r$, $s_r(t) = re^{it}, 0\leqslant t \leqslant \pi$, Cauchy's integral theorem says

$$\int_{-R}^{-\varepsilon}\frac{e^{2iz}-1}{z^2}\,dz + \int_{\varepsilon}^R \frac{e^{2iz}-1}{z^2}\,dz + \int_{S_R}\frac{e^{2iz}-1}{z^2}\,dz - \int_{s_\varepsilon}\frac{e^{2iz}-1}{z^2}\,dz = 0.$$

In the upper half-plane, we have $\lvert e^{2iz}\rvert = e^{-2\operatorname{Im} z} \leqslant 1$, so $\left\lvert \frac{e^{2iz}-1}{z^2}\right\rvert \leqslant \frac{2}{R^2}$ on $s_R$, and the integral over $s_R$ tends to $0$ as $R\to \infty$. Therefore

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{\substack{\varepsilon\to 0\\ R\to\infty}} \left(\int_{-R}^{-\varepsilon}\frac{e^{2ix}-1}{x^2}\,dx + \int_\varepsilon^R \frac{e^{2ix} - 1}{x^2}\,dx\right)
&= \lim_{\varepsilon\to 0} \int_{s_\varepsilon} \frac{e^{2iz}-1}{z^2}\,dz - \lim_{R\to\infty} \int_{s_R}\frac{e^{2iz}-1}{z^2}\,dz\\
&= \lim_{\varepsilon\to 0} \int_{s_\varepsilon} \frac{e^{2iz}-1}{z^2}\,dz.
\end{align}$$

Since $\frac{e^{2iz}-1}{z^2}$ has a simple pole in $0$, we have

$$\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0} \int_{s_\varepsilon} \frac{e^{2iz}-1}{z^2}\,dz = \pi i \operatorname{Res}\left(\frac{e^{2iz}-1}{z^2}; 0\right) = \pi i(2i) = -2\pi,$$

as can be read off the Taylor series of $e^{2iz}$. Thus

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos (2x)-1}{x^2}\,dx = -\pi.$$

---

Another way to evaluate the integral uses the trigonometric identity $\cos (2x) - 1 = - 2\sin^2 x$, which then yields

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos (2x)-1}{x^2}\,dx = -2\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin^2 x}{x^2}\,dx.$$

We can now for example integrate by parts,

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin^2 x}{x^2}\,dx &= \left[-\frac{\sin^2 x}{x}\right]_0^\infty + \int_0^\infty \frac{2\sin x\cos x}{x}\,dx\\
&= \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin (2x)}{x}\,dx\\
&= \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin t}{t}\,dt, \tag{$t = 2x$}
\end{align}$$

and evaluate that integral also via the residue theorem (or with whatever one's favourite method is).

Instead of integrating by parts, we could also have noted that

$$\int_{-1}^1 e^{-ix\xi}\,d\xi = \left[-\frac{e^{-ix\xi}}{ix}\right]_{-1}^1 = \frac{e^{ix} - e^{-ix}}{ix} = 2\frac{\sin x}{x},$$

so $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ is the Fourier transform of $\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cdot \chi_{[-1,1]}$, and Plancherel's theorem together with the parity of the integrand gives us

$$2\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin^2 x}{x^2}\,dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin^2 x}{x^2}\,dx = \frac{\pi}{2} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \chi_{[-1,1]}(x)^2\,dx = \pi.$$